# Trying to figure out how to test these data - correlation between groups for stratified/range of data?

Tags: correlation, biostatistics, kruskal-wallis-test

Apologies if some of my terminology is incorrect, I only have relatively basic stats knowledge.

I have two groups of patients where we've done some experiments on the electrical conduction within the heart. Within each group, I've got a measurement of the degree of electricity abnormality (fractionation) during different conditions.

Condition A, B and C

For each condition, I've measured abnormal electricity (% of signals that were fractionated) and because of the way we've measured, we cannot get specific values, only stratified into a range. The range is 0-24%, 25-49%, 50-74%, or 75-100%. I want to show that the degree of fractionation during condition A correlates or doesn't correlate to degree of fractionation during condition B and/or C.

I can't quite figure out which test to use in order to do this. Could someone help?

I'm using GraphPad Prism as my stats software. I'm guess very few/noone here would use that, so I just need the name of the test/an explanation of how to test for it, and I'll figure it out within the software.

Answer (score 1):

It would have been helpful if you included some more information such as sample sizes and maybe some plots. But, assuming your sample sizes are adequate, you can rank the observations (there will be ties ...), and then you can use rank-based methods, in this case (analog of one-wayt anova) this is the Kruskal-Wallis test.

For more information you can peruse the tag [kruskal-wallis-test](/questions/tagged/kruskal-wallis-test).